# Azure AD validation with python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory

I have some difficulties understanding the Graph API documentation. 
I want to check with an in-house application if a user is currently signed in.

The app has the following permissions:
- Application: Read directory data
- Delegated: Read directory data
- Delegated: Read all groups
- Delegated: Sign in and read user profile

The token is obtained at
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/{directoryId}/oauth2/token
Here is the situation:

## Theory

The documentation says to
    GET /auditLogs/signIns/{id}
    (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-get)

and gives as example:
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns/{id}
    (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.6#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q_http)

But the working API request we are using look like
    https://graph.windows.net/{directoryId}/...

## Problem

When I request
    https://graph.windows.net/{directoryId}/auditLogs/signIns/{objectIdOfUser}
I get [Request_ResourceNotFound]
    "Resource not found for the segment 'auditLogs'."

When I request (as the documentation suggests)
    https://graph.windows.net/auditLogs/signIns/{objectIdOfUser}
I get [Request_BadRequest]
    "Invalid domain name in the request url."

When I request (as the documentation example suggests)
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns/{id}
I get [InvalidAuthenticationToken]
    "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."

Can you provide us with a working example (with plain URLs) of how obtaining the 'signinStatus' ressource for the ''objectId' a given user?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have gotten a token for Azure AD Graph API, which is not the same as Microsoft Graph API.

Make sure you request the token with *resource* `https://graph.microsoft.com`.